# Button "show password" not working

Tags: jquery

I would like to write the button which show password from dots.
I mean, just change attribute "type" from password to text and when I will click again that button, password should be hide.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fieldType = $('input.password').attr("type");

  $('.show_passwrd').on("click",function(){
      if(fieldType == "password"){
          $('input.password').attr("type","text");
      }
      else{
          $('input.password').attr("type","password");
      }
  })
});
```

I do not have any errors in my browser just when I will click, nothing do.

Comment: provide html code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like dana suggested, you need to check for the fieldType inside the click handler. Also, it could be a problem with your selectors. I've shown the HTML below that would be needed to make the JavaScript work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show_passwrd').on("click", function() {
    var fieldType = $('input.password').attr("type");
    if (fieldType == "password") {
      $('input.password').attr("type", "text");
    } else {
      $('input.password').attr("type", "password");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="password" value="password" />
<input type="button" class="show_passwrd" value="show password" />
```

Comment: I don't know why It doesn't work... When I write just for show password it's working but when I add hide passowrd It doesn't work... I dont know why...

Answer (score 3):

Move the code that checks the current `type` into the event handler.  This value will change every time `.show_passwrd` is clicked and needs to be recomputed.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.show_passwrd').on("click", function() {
        var fieldType = $('input.password').attr("type");
        if (fieldType == "password"){
            $('input.password').attr("type","text");
        } else {
            $('input.password').attr("type","password");
        }
    });
});
```

Another thing to note is that the selector `input.password` is looking for an `<input>` tag with CSS class of `password`.  You may have to add it if it isn't already there or change the selector to get the element by ID:

```
<input type="password" class="password">
```

Comment: I don't know why It doesn't work... When I write just for show password it's working but when I add hide passowrd It doesn't work... I dont know why...